# small black flying insect/bug in the house all of a sudden

Tags: bathroom, humidity, moisture

it has been raining like crazy recently in my area (Maryland) for the last month and a half. I noticed that i'm seeing a lot of small flying insects (the kind that is seen on a extremely ripe banana) in the bathrooms (upstairs bath mainly) and living room sometimes.

Is it because of the increased humidity? it is always close to 65% due to the every day rain. Should I be worried that there is mold growing somewhere?

There not too many,only a few of them at a time. but I see them daily.

Comment: @chrisF, if follow your argument and go to FAQ, it says "•Identifying the source or cause of a problem within your home."... now this is a problem in my house and i am trying to identify the source. Did i miss something?

Comment: To answer your question it's probably fruit flies - which isn't really a DIY problem.

Comment: Yep. The answer would be "Call a pest control company", which isn't within the scope of a DIY website.

Comment: How about these questions then. They don't seem to fit your bill either. http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5665/stink-bug-control   

http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3806/why-is-my-house-humidity-at-80